# Changing view controllers Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am learning ios development and am trying to make an app that has two views, each with a button that when pressed will send you to the other view.  I have the two scenes set up in the storyboard and the button connected to an action.  According to what I've read, using the instantiateViewController and an identifier should be enough to change the view.  But when I run the simulator the first view appears but clicking the button has no effect.  I dont't even get a error message.

```
@IBAction func SwitchViews(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Switch view controllers
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Have you embedded navigation controller to your first view controller

Comment: I did not, is that like a container to hold the other two views?

Comment: If you are pushing viewcontroller in navigation controller you need to embed it in first view controller then your problem get solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you embed you storyboard to navigation controller.In your code navigation controller optional so controller is not able get navigation controller.

you have to embed your first storyboard to navigation controller And it will work.You can do it by In `Xcode>Editor>Embed In>Navigation Controller`.

Answer (score 2):

Just one suggestion if you are going to be developing apps that doesn't use navigation view what you have done is slightly off. The right way to do the connection to multiple views in a single view application is like this. I'll explain it in steps

Step 1 -  Add a ViewController to your story board

Step 2 - Create a cocoa touch class from file - new - file (command + N will also do the trick)

!!! *make sure its cocoa touch class* !!!

Step 3 - keep subclass of as UIViewController enter the class name keep it unique to what the view does so the code looks clean and clear for everyone.

Step 4 - Hit next and finish. Now go to the story board and add the class name to the view controller you have created inside the identity inspector and add the storyboard identifier name as well

Step 5 - link your button to an action within your swift file as TouchUpInside and add the following code

```
@IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

   let controllerVariable = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardIdentifier") as! ViewControllerClassName

   self.present(controllerVariable, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This should do the trick for creating single view applications and then building up your app with multiple screens.

But if your app uses IOS default navigation controller style like a nav bar with navigation items and a back button best practice is to use the nav controller.

If it doesn't then you have complete control over how you design your user interface by following the above steps.

Hope this helps :)